# Set Implementation Factory at Runtime

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, factory

I'm trying to figure out a way to generically register my events for any class who implements an interface registered with the dependecy injector.

In my startup class I would like to override the Implementation factory, to wrap the current creation logic, to register my events.

```
public void RegisterHubsEvents(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var crudServiceDescriptors = this.GetGenericServicesFromGenericTypeDefinition(services, typeof(IAsyncCRUDService<>));

    foreach (var serviceDescriptor in crudServiceDescriptors)
    {
        var originalFunc = serviceDescriptor.ImplementationFactory;

        Func<IServiceProvider, object> HubsRegistered = (IServiceProvider provider) => {
            var serviceObj = originalFunc(provider);
            //TODO: since this is an instance you probably need to grab the interface type first
            //or you'll risk grabbing the wrong parameter
            var dtoType = serviceObj.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First();
            var hubType = typeof(ICRUDServiceHubBase<>).MakeGenericType(dtoType);

            //Is this risky if the hub is transient will my object be disposed before the event fires?
            var hub = provider.GetService(hubType);

            var registerHubsDynamically = this.GetType().GetMethod("RegisterHubsCreate").MakeGenericMethod(dtoType);
            registerHubsDynamically.Invoke(this, new object[] { serviceObj, hub });

            return serviceObj;
        };

        serviceDescriptor.ImplementationFactory = HubsRegistered;

    }
}
```

My issue is that serviceDescriptor.ImplementationFactory is read-only, and I would like to register the events at runtime without coupling a dependency inside of my Services.

Comment: You will have to remove the original service descriptor from the `IServiceCollection` and replace it with a new one.

Comment: @steven, thanks for your reply. I saw a post you wrote about the limitations of the current dependency injection, it really helped me out thanks